# How to delay execution of code without using threads in Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I need to delay execution of some code for.. let's say 2 seconds, I have to use a Thread or a Handler like this:

```
new Thread (new Runnable() {
        public void run()
        {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) 
              {     }

            MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
            {
                public void run ()
                {
                    nextPlayerTurn();
                }
            });
        }
    }).start();
```

Is this a good approach?

The nextPlayerTurn() method calls other methods that use animations that implement OnAnimationEnd listeners (that call methods that also need to delay execution of code). My concern is that each time I use the code above, I'm creating another thread in the background that never dies.

So the question is - does the thread die once it gets to the runOnUiThread() method, no matter how long it takes for the code within runOnUiThread() to execute?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this a good approach?

It would be more efficient to do this:

```
someWidget.postDelayed(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run ()
            {
                nextPlayerTurn();
            }
        }, 2000);
```

This both performs a 2-second delay and gives you control back on the main application thread. It saves forking a thread, then having to use `runOnUiThread()` to get control back to the main application thread. Here, `someWidget` is some widget from your UI -- any will do.

> My concern is that each time I use the code above, I'm creating another thread in the background that never dies.

No, the thread will go away when `run()` of the `Runnable` you are using with the `Thread` ends.

> does the thread die once it gets to the runOnUiThread() method, no matter how long it takes for the code within runOnUiThread() to execute?

I'd phrase it as "the thread dies after it calls `runOnUiThread()`, but `runOnUiThread()` is asynchronous and takes very little time on the background thread".